# CheckBox event loop in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, loops

I have this method on my `codebehind` .cs file (.NET.Framework 4.0):

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {

            this.nombre.Enabled = false;

        } 
    }
```

So, with this I can disable that `nombre` TextBox in my aspx, everytime when I click on the checkbox.

Here's the code in aspx file:

```
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Checked="false" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Now, I want to know, a way to simplify this routine, I mean, I have plenty of textboxes, radiobuttons, etc...

So how can I achieve this using a `loop` in asp.net?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you use javascript or jquery for that? If you willing to use jquery then it will be very simple with that?

Comment: what is the logic of enable/ disable textbox with multiple checkboxes ?

Comment: Nono, i just need one checkbox, the one i show you in my post, then disable all textboxes, radiobuttons etc, with just one checkbox.

Comment: @nrsharma do you know where i can find examples of this circumstance on javascript?

Comment: @KristianKoci it's not a matter of finding examples, it's a matter of logic with some different approach. If you know javascript or jquery then you can implement logic in there with very simple code.

Comment: Yes, but i like to maintain the environment, to some extent, if i really have no choice then i go for more 'radical' solutions =) thank you! @nrsharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {    
           DisableControlsInPage(this.Page,false);    
        } 
    }

    protected void DisableControlsInPage(Control parent, bool isEnable) {
        foreach(Control c in parent.Controls) {
            if (c is TextBox) {
                ((TextBox)(c)).Enabled = isEnable;
            }
            if (c is RadioButton) {
                ((RadioButton)(c)).Enabled = isEnable;
            }    
            DisableControlsInPage(c, isEnable);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Headshottt! lol thank you very much @mit works perfectly now!!

Comment: Btw, if uncheck the checkbox they are still disabled?

Comment: In CheckBox1_CheckedChanged event write else condition with DisableControlsInPage(this.Page,true);

Answer (score 1):

you can try to get the controls and then check if it's a textbox

```
foreach(Control cont in this.Controls)
{
   if(cont.GetType() == typeof(Textbox))
   {
      (cont as Textbox).Enabled = false;
   }
}
```